# Disabling the back-off delay

Tags: c, wifi, packet, tcp

In the Wi-Fi infrastructure mode, as to let stations communicate without creating packet collision, there is a randomized back-off delay in addition to the default delay before emission.

Is it possible to reprogram the Wi-Fi protocol in C or any other language\environment and change things about the details of the implementation, like for example disable completely the randomized back-off or alter it ?

(PS : please excuse me for the weird sentences, not my native language).

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the implementation of the transmission back-off is open source, then there should be no reason why you cannot modify it.

However, this part of the protocol tends to be implemented in the WiFi radio devices, which tend to not be open source, and even if they are, tend to require specialised tools to program and debug. Sometimes there are methods to manage updating the firmware from the drivers (which allows the vendor to ship firmware upgrades via drivers), but not always, and they tend not to be public interfaces.